# Google Spreadsheet: how to determine if a date is in one of several date ranges?

Tags: date, google-sheets

On sheet A, there are n rows where each is a date range (start-date, end-date).

On sheet B, there are cells with dates.

How do I determine if the dates in sheet B are in any of the ranges of sheet A ?

The ranges may increase in number over time, i.e. once a month I'll add an additional range.

Comment: @pnuts not a puzzle but an actual question. I see it's getting downvoted. What would a more appropriate site be for it?

Comment: @pnuts Wish these questions are pinned and posted to every Q.asker asking a Q reg.Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
=sign(sumproduct(('Sheet A'!A$2:index('Sheet A'!A:A, match(1E+99, 'Sheet A'!A:A))<=A2)*('Sheet A'!B$2:index('Sheet A'!B:B, match(1E+99, 'Sheet A'!A:A))>=A2)))
```

This formula will return a positive integer when one or more matching date ranges is found; zero when no matches.

The range references to Sheet A will automatically expand as you add new date ranges. This can be proved by adding 1-Apr-2018 and 15-Apr-2018 to the bottom of the list of date ranges on Sheet A.

Linked spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_7l2FtX7wlTDuVTo-5n59FtqMHgLeIZ9APk50rxkH_c/edit?usp=sharing

[image]